# MongoDB collection creation date with PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb

I want to delete all  mongodb collection before created date today with cron. So i want MongoDB collection creation date. Can it possible to get data from database in php .

However i have below option to get date manually.

I can create new collection that will contain collection name and create date.

Answer (score 1):

From object id you can get the date, so make use of it and delete accordingly.

ObjectId is a 12-byte BSON type, constructed using:

```
a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,
a 3-byte machine identifier,
a 2-byte process id, and
a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.
```

Please check thi link : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/